# Generate runnable exe from MSTest test

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I have a [TestMethod] in a visual studio test project. If I build the project, I get a dll. I dont want to run the tests from the visual studio User Interface.

1. Is there any way to generate an exe of a test project so that i can run the tests from command prompt?
2. If I change the project type from Class Library to Console Application, then it requires a Main function. Is there any way to call a TestMethod from the Main()

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Unit tests are meant to be run in code, inside Visual Studio, and also on an automated build server.

Comment: ..that is, unless you decide to write your own utility that processes methods marked with the `TestMethodAttribute` in a given assembly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should already have an EXE that can execute your tests - mstest.exe. If you need to run your tests outside Visual Studio - and you're not using some kind of build automation solution that can already do this for you - then you can call mstest.exe and have it execute your tests.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(VS.100).aspx

Comment: I got it... mstest /testcontainer:[file.dll]

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can run the unit tests inside Visual studio through the menu: Test -> Run -> ...

Two options: 
- Tests in current context
- All tests

Context could either be project level, class level or method level. Depends on where you put your marker inside the test class or if you have selected a class/file/project in the solution explorer.

You can use the hotkey combination CTRL + R, T to run tests in current context or CTRL + R, A to run all tests.

EDIT: ref comment.

Comment: How to run the tests outside visual studio ? 
How to generate an exe of a test project ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is some sort software for test automation. My company uses [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).
Works really well, and you can use it together with source control software as well, to run the tests when someone checks something in.

Comment: Not automation. If I have a set of test cases, how to run them using command prompt or a batch file ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to utilize TFS - Microsoft Team Foundation Server, a stand-alone server-side application system to build a project and run tests inside it.

Also you can run them inside Visual Studio (menu Tests -> Run -> ...).